# New main repository

Tags: mercurial

I have a repository which I'm using for some time. Now I need to create a new main repository where I would like push my current repository. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put a lot of details, but I hope I can help.

Once you create the new main repository (using `hg clone`), you can point your current repository to it by editing the local repository's `.hg/hgrc` file and set the path to the new repository.

I hope this helps.